# How do I aggregate a count of column values across multiple tables in SQL?

Tags: sql

I have multiple tables (let's say 10 tables) as follows:

```
********  ********        *********  
* day1 *  * day2 *  ....  * day10 *  
********  ********        *********  
A B C ..  A B C ..        A B C ...  
1 4 9 ..  7 6 8 ..        9 6 2 ...  
7 2 1 ..  0 2 1 ..        0 5 1 ...  
3 3 1 ..  0 9 7 ..        1 4 1 ...  
7 8 0 ..  1 6 5 ..        2 6 1 ...  
********  ********        *********
```

I want to count the number of times column C = 1 in each table and create a new table as follows:

```
**********
* output *
**********
day   num  
 1     2  
 2     1  
 .     .  
 .     .  
10     3
**********
```

Something like this:

```
SELECT <n> AS day, COUNT(*) AS num
FROM day<n>
WHERE C = 1 AND <n> IN (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10)
```

What would be the best way to do this? (I am new to SQL)

Comment: First of all, What DBMS are you using?

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT 1 AS DAY FROM DAY1 WHERE C=1 UNION
SELECT 2 AS DAY FROM DAY2 WHERE C=1 UNION
...
SELECT 9 AS DAY FROM DAY9 WHERE C=1 UNION
SELECT 10 AS DAY FROM DAY10 WHERE C=1
```

And then do COUNT(*) GROUP BY DAY on that.

Answer (score 1):

I'm a newbie but will try my best:

Assuming you have day1 ~ day3, just three tables:

```
SELECT
    1 AS day,
    COUNT(day1.C) AS num
FROM
    day1
WHERE day1.C = 1
UNION ALL
SELECT
    2 AS day,
    COUNT(day2.C) AS num
FROM
    day2
WHERE day2.C = 1
UNION ALL
SELECT
    3 AS day,
    COUNT(day3.C) AS num
FROM
    day3
WHERE day3.C = 1
```

This will give you:

```
    day    num
1    1      2
2    2      1
3    3      3
```